# Apache Karaf 4.x, how to add feauture.xml file with bundles using console?

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

In earlier versions I could do something like this `features:addURl file:///path/to/features.xml` , but now this command is unsupported. Whats the alternative way to upload all bundles from feature.xml?

---

**Edited**

What am I doing wrong here?

I have plugin in my pom file that generates my feature.xml file in my local maven repository

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
        <artifactId>features-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-features-xml</id>
                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate-features-xml</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

My features.xml directory
[image]

Command and error

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you can use the following command:

```
feature:repo-add <path to features.xml>
```

an example would be:

```
feature:repo-add mvn:com.xyz/module-name/folder_where_xml_resides/xml/features
```

then you should be able to install your features using:

```
feature:install <feature_name>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, could you please take a look at my original question?

Comment: I found a similar issue reported here:
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/karaf-issues/201602.mbox/%3CJIRA.12936729.1454593399000.312297.1454687079948@Atlassian.JIRA%3E
May be it's a bug.